# High CPU usage when downloading file through Java

Tags: java, download, cpu-usage

I've run into a bit of a curious issue with a launcher for one of my games. When the program is run on Linux (Ubuntu) and it begins to download the LWJGL library, the CPU usage shoots up to the point where the OS is rendered nearly unusable while it's downloading. This doesn't seem to occur on Windows (tested on the same machine).

Here's the class responsible for downloading files ([source](https://bitbucket.org/mproncace/mineflat-launcher/src/7518ee8fe5453cb441ed47662d4394e50f6ff05c/MineFlat%20Launcher/src/Downloader.java?at=master)):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;

public class Downloader implements Runnable {

    private URL url;
    private String fileName;
    private String name;

    /**
     * 
     * @param url The online URL of the file to download
     * @param fileName The local file to download into
     * @param name The name to be displayed in case of error
     */

    public Downloader(URL url, String fileName, String name){
        this.url = url;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
            File file = new File(fileName);
            file.setReadable(true, false);
            file.setWritable(true, false);
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            os.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Launcher.getFileSize(url));
            os.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Launcher.progress = "Failed to download " + name;
            Launcher.fail = "Errors occurred; see console for details";
            new Launcher().repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to limit the resources available to the program without command line flags? I understand that ordinarily, one would sleep the thread, but that's not possible with my current implementation.

Comment: Try re-creating your code using java.io and see if the problem still exists. That will lead us in the right direction of determining the problem.